# How to display the boxplot with more than 2 decimal places in ggplotly

Tags: r, boxplot

I have to use ggplotly for my boxplot, but it only displays 2 decimal places.  So a lot of my values will show 0.00 in the plot.  As you can see in the example from plotly's website https://plot.ly/ggplot2/box-plots/ , only display 2 decimal.  If I use plot_ly, I can see all the decimal places as in the example https://plot.ly/r/box-plots/#version-check. Is there anyway to display all decimal in ggplotly ?  Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should've been fixed in [issue #834](https://github.com/ropensci/plotly/issues/834); according to the [changes](https://github.com/ropensci/plotly/commit/32bb3e59b63a0418099dd807e786784de90dc0ad):

> `ggplotly()` now applies `format()` to automatically generated hoverinfo. This will allow for finer control over the text displayed (for instance, `options(digits = 4)` can now be used to choose the number of significant digits used). See #834 for an example.

However, `options(digits = 4)` does *not* have any effect on the number of decimal places in a boxplot's hoverinfo; numbers are still rounded to 2 digits.

Reproducible minimal example:

```
require(ggplot2);
require(plotly);

# Sample data
set.seed(2017);
df <- cbind.data.frame(one = rnorm(100), two = rnorm(100, mean = 4));

# Plot
options(digits = 4);
ggplotly(
    ggplot(stack(df), aes(ind, values)) + geom_boxplot(aes(fill = ind)));
```

You should probably (re-open)open (the)an issue on github.

Comment: Thanks Maurits. I will open an issue.